# Alpine.js: How do I access x-data from a function in an external file?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm just starting out with Alpine.js, I understand the basics but I'm having trouble applying them when moving functions outside of inline script tags.

For example, in `index.html`:

```html
<div x-data="{ loading: false }"/>
  <button
    onClick="post()"
    :class="{ 'active': loading === true }"
  >
    Post Comment
  </button>
</div>
```

if `post()` was in `main.ts`:

```js
const postComment = () => {
  this.loading = true;
};

window.postComment = postComment;
```

How do I make it so that `this` isn't undefined?

I've found plenty of examples where functions are kept within `index.html`, but none where they're in a separate file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to add the method to the AlpineJs instance to access the same scope. But you can do this with some object destructuring using the spread `...` operator:

In the page:

```
<div x-data="{
  isLoading: false,
  ...utils
}">
    // Your content
</div>
```

Then in your external script file:

```
const utils = {
  post(){
    this.isLoading = true
  }
}

window.utils = utils
```

The nice thing about this is you could put everything you need for a loading indicator in this external object to use as a mixin wherever you need it.

Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/stephenoldham/pen/BapvyYr

---

**Update for AlpineJs v3:**

If you're trying to achieve the same goal in the latest version of AlpineJs you'll need to use the Data Directive:

In the page:

```
<div x-data="utils">
    // Your content
</div>
```

Then in your external script file:

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
    Alpine.data('utils', () => ({
        isLoading: false,
        post(){
            this.isLoading = true

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.isLoading = false
            }, 3000)
        }
    }))
})
```

Here's a working example:
https://codepen.io/stephenoldham-the-vuer/pen/dyJEjRx?editors=1100

Further reading in the docs covers how to set initial values and more:
https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data

Comment: That simple operator finally gave me a working solution after roughly 20 hours of pain with AlpineJS + Laravel 9 + Blade templating. If someone is in this position then just use the {{ }} syntax to pass your instance data to the x-data definition (where Steve has written false) and then you can access it in the external function to make your ajax requests using axios or fetch().... or do whatever else you're using Alpine for.

Laravel Mix ships with Alpine out of the box, hence my usage. I hope this helps if someone is looking for the same solution and comes across this answer from Steve.

Comment: Hi @Steve O, i copied exactly the code you posted - and got this error:

**Expression Error: utils is not defined** 

Is this solution still valid in Alpine3.9.1 ?

Comment: @AlexandruCristian No you'll want to update to use the Alpine Data Directive. I've edited my answer above with an example :)